# Not able to access data using 'categories.products .all ' in template view. Django Models with foreign key

Tags: python, django, templates, view

I have models that have relation using a foreign key.

```
class Cat1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    productId = models.AutoField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    productType = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    matType = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='Use comma , to seperate multiple materials') 
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sellers',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='NA')
    cat_1 = models.ForeignKey(Cat1,related_name='catlevel1',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='NA')
```

Then i have my views of the page.
where i need to display all the product from the category i have clicked on.
My View is :

```
def cat_products(request,pk):
   categories = get_object_or_404(Cat1, pk=pk) #here the categories get the category i clicked on homepage.
   products = Product.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'products.html', {'categories':categories,'products':products})
```

Then products.html is:

```
<!--Full Code not shown for easy understanding-->
{% for prod in categories.products.all %}

       {{categories.name}} 
        <tr>
          <td>{{ prod.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ prod.matType }}</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

[image: Webpage is categories.products.all in for loop]
So basically categories is the the name that can be used to access current category.Products is the list of all products.

I have tried this code above which yield no result.
Now the code below shows all the products objects.

```
<!--Full Code not shown for easy understanding-->
{% for prod in products %}

       {{categories.name}} 
        <tr>
          <td>{{ prod.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ prod.matType }}</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

[image: Webpage with only 'products' in for loop]

But this way it shows all products irrespective of categories.
So this party shirt in Men category is shown in Women too.

[image: Webpage of Women Category products]

i have tried only printing all the products
`{% for prod in products %}`
The line in code above `{{categories.name}}` shows the name of the class. 
This works fine with no problem.

The backend is able to access the database no problem but i am not able to figure out the template section
Here is the product and the categories stored as Men in product object.
[image: Django Admin Panel With product Details.]

I should be able to see Men category products in men and Women products in women category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `catlevel1` instead of products:

```
{% for prod in categories.catlevel1.all %}

   {{categories.name}} 
    <tr>
      <td>{{ prod.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ prod.matType }}</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Because you have defined [**`related_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) as `catlevel1` when you created the ForeignKey relation between `Product` and `Cat1`.

Comment: Thank You Very Much !! I have been trying to sort this out since morning. Finally i can proceed. I didn't know that was the case and how related names are to be used. I am new to Django.